# Asus G750JH with pre-installed Windows 8 - I want to dual boot ArchLinux

Tags: arch-linux, windows, dual-boot, boot-loader, uefi

I have a new Asus G759JH laptop and it has Windows 8 installed on it. I have resized and fixed the partitions in a way I thought would work (now, I'm not sure that what I've done is actually going to work due to UEFI, which is the big problem here) but I have not dared touching the EFI partition other than mounting it to /boot/efi as a step on Arch's wiki suggested if you wanted to use the EFISTAB boot option. (?)

So, I got to the step where I would normally install grub and chain-boot it through windows->grub->arch but I didn't want to mess anything up because I don't have time to do recovery work on it if I do mess up...

Anyway, so to the point:

I have my partitions for Windows, like normal, and my partitions for Linux. The Linux partitions are on the SSD disk along with the partitions for Windows. And What I'm not sure is how to give me the option of booting either Windows 8 or Arch as soon as possible. With that I mean where/how do I set it up so that I can pick either one as early in the boot process as possible.

What I gathered about UEFI is that each OS can have their own EFI firmware or something and that you could boot different ones and go that way, or chain-load it if I go into Legacy mode. Or something like that. This is the whole reason I'm asking this question, becuase I'm very very confused.

So how do I add the option of booting Arch through UEFI and not Legacy mode? If possible.

Edit:
One thing that confused me that I would want clarified is this: If I have Windows on the EFI partition (which btw is only 100mb, but as far as I know I can't resize without wiping windows) does grub just add my ArchLinux entry to it or is it a chain-load or is it wiping it clean?

That's where I actually got stuck yesterday when I tried to do it on my own. I wasn't sure what it would do so I didn't do anything without being certain.

Answer (score 1):

install the `grub-efi` package, which will add an EFI bootentry that goes directly to grub.

you will then have an (EFI) boot options to boot either into w32 or into grub/arch or from CD/DVD or ...

*note* that i'm on Debian, so i don't know the exact name of the package for *arch*; just search for `grub` *and* `efi`.

Comment: Can you describe what that package will do?
I have a package installed efivar and another called something else, with grub. But I'm curious to how to do it in the way I specified. Will this do that?

Comment: i added a (short) description of what the package does; the `efivar` package is needed to interact with EFI (but doesn't do anything on it's own); i cannot say what the package "called something else, with grub" does.

Comment: @umläaute I meant efibootmgr and I meant what you were telling me. Like, explain to me why you said what you said. Explain how I would go about to fix it etc. Because I already knew that I needed some kind of efi-packages etc. At the moment I'm reading up on the EFI system so that maybe it will give me a hint on how to edit my entry I currently have in my UEFI so that it points to the correct place.

Answer (score -1):

I have finally succeded to tripleboot my ASUS G750 JH with Linux Mint (which is based entirely on Ubuntu) and Linux Manjaro (entirely based on Arch).

I did like this: 
1. Created partitions one for Mint one for Manjaro on the SSD disk after shrink of Windows partition and deletion of the 20 GB Windows recovery
partition at the end of the SSD which was instead copied to an recovery USB with ASUS BAcktrack.

1. Started computer with F2 kept pressed until BIOSmeny appeared and put secure boot to disable and disabled fastboot in Windows
2. Installed Manjaro on one of the partitions from a DVD. To start from the DVD I kept Esc pressed until boot menu appeared and
   chose UEFIDVD as boot option. I did NOT install any bootloader for Manjaro at all
3. Then I started from a liveDVD with Mint. Started from the option UEFIDVD NOT the normal DVD option.
4. Installed Mint in its partition and the bootloader, GRUB, in the EFI partition of the Windows installation. On my computer it was DEV/sdb1
5. Restart. Now GRUB appears first and has Mint, Windows and Manjaro listed as boot choices. All work!

Good luck!

Comment: reread the question